# C++ MFC What is the underlying class type for Picture Control?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm having difficulty identifying the underlying type for a C++ MFC Picture Control.

For example, the tool identified as "Edit Control" in resource view properties has an underlying type of 'CEdit'.

What is the equivalent for Picture Control.

Is there a way that I identify classes for controls in Visual Studio, or is there a resource online somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: CStatic it is . Anyway, you really want to go the MFC route nowadays?

Comment: Thanks afraid so on MFC. I need native execution with no framework / library dependency. It's a first C++ windows application for me, and I have been informed that MFC experience is prerequisite to WTL use, so MFC it is for now!

Comment: @grx - "native execution with no framework/library dependency" is the polar opposite and at direct odds to MFC and/or WTL use. :confused:

Comment: @enhzflep but MFC and WTL can be statically compiled thus avoiding framework/library dependency.

Comment: @grx - well, then I guess it depends on your definition of "framework/library dependency". If I don't have MFC and as a result, can't build your project, then it has a dependency of MFC, simple as that. wxWidgets, Qt, GTK are all libraries/frameworks, yet they too can be statically linked, thus - all library code _is_ included in the binary. If your only requirement is that you dont have to install extra libs on the machine running your program, there are other available options. I use wxWidgets, since exactly the same code builds and runs on 32/64 Windows, x64 Linux and ARM-based RaspberryPi.

Comment: To clarify then, "native execution with no external framework/library dependency on the client machine". I've not heard of wxWidgets, I will give that a look. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand MFC without knowing the Windows API isn't going to be very successful. Likewise, MFC is not a prerequisite to learning WTL. For both frameworks, a solid understanding of the Windows API **is** mandatory. Start with [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) (and try to get a copy of [Petzold's *Programming Windows*](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/)).